# Plots behind the axes

Tags: pgfplots

How to move the axes in front of plots? The example below produces plots which are blocking the axes. I want those plots to be behind the axes.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{paralist,pst-func, pst-plot, pst-math, pstricks-add,pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns,matrix,arrows}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[axis lines=center,clip=false,xmin=-4,xmax=4,ymin=0,ymax=1] 
    \addplot[color=lime,fill=lime, samples=100] {1/sqrt(2)*exp(-(x+1)^2/1)} \closedcycle;
    \addplot[color=cyan!40,fill=cyan!40, samples=100] {1/sqrt(2)*exp(-(x-1)^2/1)} \closedcycle;
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Add `axis on top` to the `axis` options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use axis on top

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns,matrix,arrows}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[axis lines=center,clip=false,xmin=-4,xmax=4,ymin=0,ymax=1,axis on top]
    \addplot[color=lime,fill=lime, samples=100] {1/sqrt(2)*exp(-(x+1)^2/1)} \closedcycle;
    \addplot[color=cyan!40,fill=cyan!40, samples=100] {1/sqrt(2)*exp(-(x-1)^2/1)} \closedcycle;
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Impossible to be a more natural solution. Nice!